# Unable to use an existing Hive permanent UDF from Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have previously registered a UDF with hive. It is permanent not `TEMPORARY`. It works in beeline.

```
CREATE FUNCTION normaliseURL AS 'com.example.hive.udfs.NormaliseURL' USING JAR 'hdfs://udfs/hive-udfs.jar';
```

I have spark configured to use the hive metastore. The config is working as I can query hive tables. I can see the UDF;

```
In [9]: spark.sql('describe function normaliseURL').show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------+
|function_desc                              |
+-------------------------------------------+
|Function: default.normaliseURL             |
|Class: com.example.hive.udfs.NormaliseURL  |
|Usage: N/A.                                |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

However I cannot use the UDF in a sql statement;

```
spark.sql('SELECT normaliseURL("value")')
AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'default.normaliseURL'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7"
```

If I attempt to register the UDF with spark (bypassing the metastore) it fails to register it, suggesting that it does already exist.

```
In [12]: spark.sql("create function normaliseURL as 'com.example.hive.udfs.NormaliseURL'")
AnalysisException: "Function 'default.normaliseURL' already exists in database 'default';"
```

I'm using Spark 2.0, hive metastore 1.1.0. The UDF is scala, my spark driver code is python.

I'm stumped.

- Am I correct in my assumption that Spark can utilise metastore-defined permanent UDFs?
- Am I creating the function correctly in hive?

Comment: In your `SparkSession.builder` did you defined `enableHiveSupport()`?

Comment: Yeah I did. I can see, and query hive-defined tables from spark so I assume hive support is enabled appropriately.

Comment: Humm... Did you defined your UDF jar in spark-submit or spark-shell call? Like: `./bin/spark-shell --jars <path-to-your-hive-udf>.jar`

Comment: @RobCowie: are you sure the `DataType` of `value` column is same in both UDF Class(in Scala) and the query what it returns?

Comment: can you paste `com.example.hive.udfs.NormaliseURL` code ?

Comment: try `spark.sql('SELECT normaliseURL("value") from values(1)')`

Comment: Hi, i suppose that the jar your are using for the udf is not available to spark and you get that error, try to check this answer as it seems to me to be your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272446/defined-spark-permanent-udf-which-can-see-in-metastore-but-can-not-use-in-hive-s

Answer (score 2):

Issue is Spark 2.0 is not able to execute the functions whose JARs are located on HDFS.

[Spark SQL: Thriftserver unable to run a registered Hive UDTF](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18832)

One workaround is to define the function as a temporary function in Spark job with jar path pointing to a local edge-node path. Then call the function in same Spark job.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION functionName as 'com.test.HiveUDF' USING JAR '/user/home/dir1/functions.jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work on spark on yarn environment however as suggested you need to use `spark-shell --jars <path-to-your-hive-udf>.jar` not in hdfs but in local.